# How to store string spaces as null in numeric column

Tags: postgresql

I want to get records from my local txt file to postgresql table.

I have created following table.

`create table player_info
(
Name varchar(20),
City varchar(30),
State varchar(30),
DateOfTour date,
pay numeric(5),
flag char
)`

And, my local txt file contains following data.

`John|Mumbai| |20170203|55555|Y
David|Mumbai| |20170305|   |N
Romcy|Mumbai| |20170405|55555|N
Gotry|Mumbai| |20170708|   |Y`

I am just executing this,

`copy player_info (Name,
City,
State,
DateOfTour,
pay_id,
flag)
from local 'D:\sample_player_info.txt' 
delimiter '|' null as ''
exceptions 'D:\Logs\player_info'`

What I want is,
For my numeric column, If 3 spaces are there, 
then I have to insert NULL as pay else whatever 5 digits numeric number.

pay is a column in my table whose datatype is numeric.

Is this correct or possible to do this ?

Comment: can't you run an update query to make 3 spaces to null after copy command?

Comment: Do you get an error if you try it as is?

Comment: @WannaBeSqlExpert : I can run but firstly I want that 3 spaces data in my numeric column. Which is not coming as is

Comment: @Andrew : Yes As I have a log file..  So it is showing an error about numeric. And remaining records get inserted into table.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by wanting 3 spaces in the numeric column. I recommend pre-processing the txt file with awk or sed to delete the three spaces. Then it will be imported as a NULL, matching the NULL AS clause. (Works in your State column already.) If you mean you want to store either a number or spaces, numeric won't do that, but why would you want to? You can always convert NULL to spaces on output.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store strings in a numeric column, at all. 3 spaces is a string, so it cannot be stored in the column `pay` as that is defined as numeric.

A common approach to this conundrum is to create a `staging table` which uses less precise data types in the column definitions. Import the source data into the staging table. Then process that data so that it can be reliably added to the final table. e.g. in the `staging table` set a column called `pay_str` to NULL where `pay_str` = '   '  (or perhaps LIKE ' %')